# Regex to match pipe (|) or end of line

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following regex to match name-value pairs:

```
^(?<NameValue>(?<Name>[A-Z][\w]*):(?<Value>[\w]*)(?=(\||\z)))+$
```

I trying to match the pipe character or end of line. Essentially it should match text like

```
Setting1:Value1|Setting2:Value2|Setting3:Value3
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong. It's been a while since I've had regex stump me like this :)
Update:
Ended up with

```
^(?:(?<NameValue>(?<Name>[A-Z][\w]*):(?<Value>[\w]*))(?m:\||$))+
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Wouldn't  `string.Split` simpler?

Comment: String.Split is great if you're already certain the data is formatted correctly.

Comment: And your text seems like a perfect candidate for it.

Comment: It would be if I had control over the source. Regex provides validation and parsing all in one. String.Split doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex to match pipe or end of line:

```
(?m:\||$)
```

The `m`ultiline flag makes `$` match end of line.

`\z` will only match end of string, never end of line.

You could use an expression like:

```
var re = @"(?xm)
    \A
    (?:
       (?<Name>[A-Z]\w*)
       :
       (?<Value>\w*)
       (?: \| | $ )
    )+
    \z";
```